# How to retrieve List Item link contents in SharePoint via PHP SOAP?

Tags: sharepoint-online, soap, php

Good Day,

Our project needs us to access a certain List in SharePoint and download documents from there using SoapClient and NTLM as mode.

I am able to connect to SharePoint and retrieve the items on the List by looping through the XML and getting the `ows_LinkTitle` attribute. For each List item "link", we need to access those links and be able to know its depth and the contents that it has. I've seen a similar problem as mine here on Stack but unfortunately his is using php_SPO which is utilizing REST ([How can I Download/Access SharePoint Online Documents using PHP / XML / SOAP?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/215225/how-can-i-download-access-sharepoint-online-documents-using-php-xml-soap)).

Any help is appreaciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Online does not support NTLM or Kerberos. Instead you should use the OAuth pattern and avoid using SOAP as it is deprecated.

[This previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005601/how-to-authenticate-with-sharepoint-online-for-a-php-app) will likely be helpful; the top voted answer includes a link to a [PHP library](https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO) which implements OAuth for SPO using the App ID + Secret pattern (note I strongly recommend not using the username/password pattern as that is insecure).

I would then review [Working with folders and files with REST](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest) to download your documents.

There is also the "v2" or modern way of doing this via [Graph API](https://docs.microsoft.com/graph/api/resources/onedrive?view=graph-rest-1.0).